# AngularJS custom directive works in FF16 but not in IE or Chrome

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that renders either an active or disabled file link depending on whether an input attribute id is present or not.

The directive is called filelink:

```
<filelink id="{{resource.id}}" type="{{resource.mimetype}}" name="{{resource.name}}" size="{{resource.size}}" icon="hide"></filelink>
```

This is the directive code:

```
.directive('filelink', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        scope: true,
        template:"<span></span>",
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $attrs.$observe('id', function (value) {
                if(value == ""){
                    $element.append("<span class='heading' href=''>  "+$attrs.name+" <i class='icon-lock'></i></span>")
                }else{
                    $element.append("<a class='heading' href='t3a/index.php?id=5&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[controller]=Dataset&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[action]=readFile&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[id]="+$attrs.id+"&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[type]="+$attrs.type+"&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[name]="+$attrs.name+"&tx_crcdata_crc_data_mgm[size]="+$attrs.size+"' style='padding-left: 10px;' title='"+$attrs.name+"'>  "+$attrs.name+" </a> ")
                 }
             });
          }
        };
      });
```

The id value is being received asynchronously through a resolver outside of the controller:

```
DatasetDetailCtrl.resolve = {
  dataset: function($route, Package) {
    Package.getSinglePackage($route.current.params.datasetId);
  },
  delay: function($q, $timeout) {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
    return delay.promise;
  }
};
```

The directive works perfectly fine in Firefox 16 but in Chrome and IE the directive does not work because all the $attrs are "undefined". It seems that observing the async called data is not working

Any ideas why this is the case ?

Comment: I would first try to hardcode an ID to see whether the error is related to the directive or the resolver. Is it possible to set up a jsFiddle (or something like that) which reproduces the bug?

Comment: To get a better understanding of this, is your filelink in an ng-repeat?